# Listview to SimpleAdapter not working

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have code in one Activity as shown below and it works well.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_ID, catid);
map.put(TAG_NAME, catname);                 
oslist.add(map);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);                                
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
R.layout.category_list,
new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME}, new int[] {
R.id.catid,R.id.catname});
```

While similar code in another Activity is not working...

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(newsList.this, oslist,
R.layout.category_list,
new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME}, new int[] {
R.id.catid,R.id.catname});
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It gives error like :

```
The constructor SimpleAdapter(newsList, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined
```

Comment: please, see this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10099967/3640637

hope be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `newsList.this` you should be passing a Context, probably the `Activity2.this`, assuming your second `Activity` is called Activity2.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass context in the constructor of your adapter like:

//Declare global

```
Contect _ctx = youractivityname.this
```

and then pass it to your adapter like:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(_ctx, oslist,R.layout.category_list,new String[] {    TAG_ID,TAG_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.catid,R.id.catname});
```

Comment: When I write Context _ctx = newsList.this; It gives following error